# Yum not Detected

Tags: ssh, fedora, yum

I am trying to use SSH to update PHP and I'm getting the message "Yum not Detected."

Is "Yum" something I need to enable or install?

Following advice I got in a previous question, I typed this into SSH:

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

And it displayed this:

```
Fedora Core release 6 (Zod)
Fedora Core release 6 (Zod)
```

Should Yum work on my server?  If yes, how can I get it to work?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Who did you piss off to get stuck maintaining a FC6 machine?

Comment: LOL... is it bad?  I just bought it from Network Solutions.

Comment: I just checked the Network Solutions Homepage. They have a money back guarantee for the first 30 days. [Get your money back](http://www.networksolutions.com/info/popup-30-day-guarantee.jsp). Fedora Core 6 IS that bad because the operating system will celebrate its fifth birthday this year (current release is 14). Packages are quite outdated and you are stuck with no support.

Comment: I completely agree with pacey. FC6 has been officially unsupported since November 2007, they were downright negligent to hand it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try `rpm -q yum` to discover if yum package is installed.

Comment: thanks... when I did that it says "package yum is not installed"... is it possible for me to install it?

Answer (score 2):

Use this as a template

```
http://godaddyvds.wikispaces.com/installing+yum
```

That is for fedora 4.. So you just use that as a guide for which packages to install

For 6 it will be

```
http://archive.kernel.org/fedora-archive/core/6/i386/os/Fedora/RPMS/ for 32 bit
http://archive.kernel.org/fedora-archive/core/6/x86_64/os/Fedora/RPMS/ for 64 bit
```

**EDIT**

Ok for example.. the first file is

```
python-elementtree-1.2.6-4.i386.rpm
```

So if its a 32 bit version.. I go to the 32bit URL and find the python-elementtree file which is

```
http://archive.kernel.org/fedora-archive/core/6/i386/os/Fedora/RPMS/python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.i386.rpm
```

Use that URL in place of the one in the example.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks... so do I just look for the equivalents of the 6 URLs shown in the godaddyvds wiki and paste them all into SSH?

Comment: I made an edit on what to look for and replace it with